# Add directory exception to Symfony URL rewritings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, url-rewriting

This project where I am working on was completely developed in Symfony. The source code is in a directory named `intranet` inside the root `www` folder.

Inside it (*www/intranet/*) I created a new directory called `financial` with a different source code and I wanted Apache not to perform any kind of redirection in it. But When I try to access any of the the PHP files in financial (*www/intranet/financial/*) it sends me to a blank page with nothing in the source code (checked when I press CTRL+U).

I want Symfony to keep working correctly but to access this folder `financial` directly, without any rewriting.

This is what I got in my **.htaccess** file, that is located in `www/intranet/web/`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I really don't know where to start to solve this problem. Pages are blank, and I am not sure if the problem is in the **.htaccess** or in the **httpd.conf**.

Note that my part is not written in Symfony. I don't care the URL I will need to use, I just want to not be redirected or denied

Can any of you help me with this??

Comment: What url do you use to access that folder? You need to bypass Symfony  front controller. If I understand you correctly, you put some code in for instance: apache-htdocs/symfony-project/web/some-diretory/some-script.php You can access that code directly like this: http://localhost/symfony-project/web/some-directory/some-script.php

Comment: this is one of the problems. When I type localhost in the browser, I go to the login page (that is somewhere inside the `intranet` folder).

I want to access my files by going to localhost/intranet/financial/... or localhost/financial/... 

notice that my part is not written in Symfony!